# How to compare text semantically

Tags: computer-science, semantics

Lets say you have a bunch of book description. Whats would be the technic to make this text comparable to each other, so i can group books which have simular subjects.

Comment: What you are describing may be achieved using tags; though, it does add a human element to the equation, unless you come up with your own algorithm to, say, separate the words in the description and develop a rank by word usage.  Example: If both descriptions include *Food* and *Cook*, you may logically group them in a *Food* and/or *Cooking* category.

Comment: As jeremy said, tags should suit you just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a very large number of algorithms and techniques for determining the [similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity) of two units of text. If you didn't care about the meanings, and were just interested in the lexical similarity of two strings, there are a bunch of techniques for [string similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aString_similarity_measures), of which Levenshtein distance is one of the most well-known, if not the best performing. However, you explicitly stated you want semantic similarity, so the WikiPedia page on [latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) will give you a good starting point. Very roughly speaking, LSA looks for documents which contain higher-than-the-average occurrence of less commonly used terms (words or word-phrases), and clusters documents based on the frequency of use of the uncommon terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Jaccard's similarity coefficient if you want something to compare at say sentence level. Treating each sentence as the smallest unit. You can drill down to words depending on the need.
This doesn't really solve the "semantic" part of your problem but works as a good string similarity algorithm.